# Android properties that can be animated with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I am starting to play around with Property Animations over view animations as I have a view that needs to scale and push others out of the way as it does. I've seen some examples but I'm just wondering if there is anywhere that provides a list of the properties that can be altered using these classes. For example, I saw one tutorial that did a quick rotation using:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView, "rotation", 360)
```

Which is quite cool, but I wouldn't have known the rotation property if not for that exact tutorial, is there any comprehensive list of what can be done? The particular property I want to animate is the weight of a view within a LinearLayout, if anyone has any advice on that specifically.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Better late than never, so here is the comprehensive list of the properties that can be animated with ObjectAnimator.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views

Comment: I am curious if that is the complete list? On 9OldAndroid, there is an example that animates the background color of a view, which is not specified in the list. http://nineoldandroids.com/ `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "backgroundColor", /*Red*/0xFFFF8080, /*Blue*/0xFF8080FF);`

Comment: The list is not complete, there's at list "xFraction" and "yFraction" that works (saw in [DevBytes Sliding Fragments sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbl5cxfA1n4))

Comment: A complete list won't exist given that it works with anything that has a properly name getter/setter (reflection), or by defining a custom Property. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381280/1290264.

Comment: This list isn't even remotely comprehensive since it can be used on any accessible object with any accessible setter.

Answer (score 28):

The [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator) imply that any value can be used with `ObjectAnimator` as long as you follow a naming convention:

> 1. The object property that you are animating must have a setter function (in camel case) in the form of `set<propertyName>()`. Because
>      the ObjectAnimator automatically updates the property during
>      animation, it must be able to access the property with this setter
>      method. For example, if the property name is `foo`, you need to have a
>      `setFoo()` method. If this setter method does not exist, you have three
>      options:
>
>    - Add the setter method to the class if you have the rights to
>        do so.
>    - Use a wrapper class that you have rights to change and have
>        that wrapper receive the value with a valid setter method and forward
>        it to the original object.
>    - Use ValueAnimator instead.
> 2. [...]

---

With respect to your question, [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation) has the method `setRotation(float)` -- that gives you a hint it can be used. In particular here's how you would do it with a particular [`TimeInterpolator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html):

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotation", 0f, 90f);
anim.setDuration(2000);                  // Duration in milliseconds
anim.setInterpolator(timeInterpolator);  // E.g. Linear, Accelerate, Decelerate
anim.start()                             // Begin the animation
```

You can read the docs for more details on the expectations of `ObjectAnimator`.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the comprehensive list of property names that you are looking for:

- rotation
- rotationX
- rotationY
- translationX
- translationY
- scaleX
- scaleY
- pivotX
- pivotY
- alpha
- x
- y

Source: [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views)

Answer (score 0):

Use "**translateX**" or "**transalteY**" to move a `<group>` 
Take a look at [vectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it at the `View.java` file in `Properties` block. Now it starts with the line of:

```
public static final Property<View, Float> ALPHA = new FloatProperty<View>("alpha")
```