# How does Android ObjectAnimator recognize the attributes setter methods?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, objectanimator

How is ObjectAnimator able to call the appropriate method `setX` if the attribute `x` is specified as a string? What I mean is, what technique is used to recognize that I want to animate the attribute `rotation` of my view and call the appropriate method `setRotation` of that view?

I've already understood how ObjectAnimator works and have managed to use it, it is quite simple, I am just curious about the operating principles.

Comment: For property "foo" a method setFoo is called via reflaction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of ways to animate the rotation of a view:

**1.** `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, 90f).start();`

This uses [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) to call the `setRotation(float f)` and `float getRotation()` methods of the view.

You can use this method to animate any property of a class as long as that class has implemented the appropriate getter and setter methods for that property.

But reflection is a slow operation, so there is a second method that doesn't use reflection.

**2.** `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ROTATION, 0f, 90f).start();`

This uses the rotation Property of the view. [Property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Property.html) is an abstract class that defines the `setValue(T)` and the `T get()` methods which in turn call the actual getter and setter of the supplied object. For example, the rotation property on the `View` class uses the following code:

```
public static final Property<View, Float> ROTATION = new FloatProperty<View>("rotation") {
    @Override
    public void setValue(View object, float value) {
        object.setRotation(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Float get(View object) {
        return object.getRotation();
    }
};
```

If you want to animate a custom property of an object, you can implement your own Property like the one above.

Then there is a third method, which also doesn't use reflection.

**3.** `view.animate().rotation(90f);`

This one has a fluent interface so it's easier to use. You can also chain multiple animations to run together, for example: `view.animate().rotation(90f).translationX(10f);`

The downside of this method is that you can only animate the standard properties of a View and not custom properties or properties on your own classes.

Comment: Ugh, using reflection to animate Object sounds so bad, it should not even be possible !